# How to reload div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with reloading div content.
I have a form which is split in 4 steps.
On the second step people are able to add items (giftcards or checks)
When someone adds a new item this item is added to an array which is stored in a session.
After adding the item I would like to show the item to the customer so I wanted to refresh / reload the div with the PHP function that shows the data.

```
<div class="kosten" id="kosten">
                <?php
                    if($session->exists('stap2')) {
                        echo $lijst->output();
                    }
                ?>
</div>
```

The function `exists` is to check if a sessions has been set.
The function `output` is a function to output html with session data.

***So what have I tried so far:***
First I tried to do something like:

```
$('#kosten').load('index.php');
```

This however resulted in showing me the index.php but I was back at step 1. I also tried to add some JavaScript / jQuery to show step 2 again but this also didn't help

Second thing I tried:

```
setInterval(function() {
                    $('#kosten').text();
                }, 3000);
```

Which resulted in showing me a half blank page. It wouldn't reload the bottom half of the page. And with an interval you will also see that the div is being reloaded.

Third thing I have tried is to do another post to PHP. It would than `echo $lijst->output()` as a return. But this gave me an array instead of html

So what I would like to do is reload the div so not the page after a button of "add item" is clicked. Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with adding another $.post. There I echoed the required function

```
echo $lijst->output();
```

After that I could use that as the `answer` of the function which I then could use for

```
$('.kosten').html(answer);
```

Doing this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the option of adding a selector to do what you look for:

```
$('#kosten').load('index.php #kosten');
```

Comment: If I do that it will also send me back to the first step which I try to avoid

Comment: Wait, so how does the server know it should return step 2 and not step 1 in the first place?

Comment: Because `output()` will only be used for step 2. And also because in the file where all of the ajax posts are handled this will only be used for `step2` and `output()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what index.php contains, but you can try to add index.php page url instead of 'index.php' only.

```
$('#kosten').load('url of index.php');
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter. I believe tough that it should always return to the index.php of the domain. Except when you call the function from inside another folder